# Changing row in data frame to ffactor

Tags: dataframe

I have a data frame where the last column is a numerical variable that shows the location of the row (so basically it starts at 1 and ends at the number of the last row).

I want to change that into a factor so that the first 10 are level = "First 10", second 10 are level = "Second 10"
I am unable to think of where to start except by as.factor